# Android Camera Capture using FFmpeg

Tags: android, ffmpeg, android-camera

Am tryin' to take the preview frame generated by the android camera and pass the `data[]` to ffmpeg input pipe to generate a flv video.
The command that I used was :

```
ffmpeg -f image2pipe -i pipe: -f flv -vcodec libx264 out.flv
```

I've also tried to force the input format to `yuv4mpegpipe` and `rawvideo` but with no success...
The default format of the preview frame generated by android-camera is `NV21`.
The way am invokin' ffmpeg is through the `Process API` and writing the preview frames `data[]` to the process' `stdin`...
The `onPreviewFrame()` definition is as follows :

```
public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera camera)
{   
    try
    {
        processIn.write(data);
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Log.e(TAG, FUNCTION + " : " + e.getMessage());
    }               
    camera.addCallbackBuffer(new byte[bufferSize]);
}
```

`processIn` is connected to the `ffmpeg` process `stdin` and `buffersize` is computed based on the documentation provided for `addCallbackBuffer()`.
Is there something that am doin' wrong...?

Thanks...

Comment: could you explain how you invoked the ffmpeg process by using the process api?

Comment: Never try `camera.addCallbackBuffer(new byte[bufferSize])`: you should return (i.e. `addCallbackBuffer()`) the **data** array that you received from the Camera callback.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Kinda got it working perfectly...
The mistake that seemed to be happenin' was related to the `vcodec` of the image stream.
Seems that ffmpeg has no provision to decode `NV21` format images or image stream.
For that had to convert the `NV21` format preview frame to `JPEG` and as the images had to streamed in real time to the `ffmpeg` process ,the conversion had to be `On the Fly`. The closest reliable solution for `On the Fly` conversion to `JPEG` was as follows :

```
public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera camera)
{
        if(isFirstFrame)
    {
        Camera.Parameters cameraParam = camera.getParameters();
        Camera.Size previewSize = cameraParam.getPreviewSize();
        previewFormat = cameraParam.getPreviewFormat();
        frameWidth = previewSize.width;
        frameHeight = previewSize.height;
        frameRect = new Rect(0, 0, frameWidth, frameHeight);
        isFirstFrame = false;
    }

    previewImage = new YuvImage(data, previewFormat, frameWidth, frameHeight, null);

    if(previewImage.compressToJpeg(frameRect, 50, processIn))
        Log.d(TAG, "Data : " + data.length);

    previewImage = null;

    camera.addCallbackBuffer(new byte[bufferSize]);
}
```

And the `ffmpeg` command used was :

```
ffmpeg -f image2pipe -vcodec mjpeg -i - -f flv -vcodec libx264 out.flv
```

Comment: Hi, Can you share your code? I want to know how you use `processIn`. Thanks

Comment: I am getting unsupported format "mjpeg" on Android when I try this code using a static build of ffmpeg. What is the solution for that?

Comment: also did you run your command on a static build of ffmpeg on Android or did u try this command on desktop?